# How to determine Acceleration and Deceleration from top speed and distance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration

> A cyclist starts from rest from her school and accelerates uniformly to reach Bus Stop A at a speed of 6 m/s.  She then cycles at constant speed for some time till she reaches Bus Stop B.  Then, she decelerates uniformly and comes to rest when she reaches her house.  The distance between Bus Stop A and B is half of the total distance covered.  If the acceleration is twice the deceleration and her total travel time is 30 seconds, find the acceleration.

I kind of don't know how to approach this question. I tried the kinematics equations of motion, the average velocity formula but nothing turned out to me.